# About Integrals and Symmetry

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, symmetry

Can anyone give me some help with this problem? I have never worked with such kind of problem and I am a bit confused, specially about what he means with "using symmetry".

> If $B_1=B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, using symmetry, show that:
>
> \begin{align}
>  \int_{\partial B_{1}} x_j \mathrm{d}S = \int_{\partial B_{1}} x_j x_k \mathrm{d}S = 0, \,\,\,\mathrm{for} \,\,\,j\neq k 
> \end{align}
> and
> \begin{align}
>  \int_{\partial B_{1}} x_k^{2} \mathrm{d}S = n ^{-1}\int_{\partial B_{1}} \left[ 
>  \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j^{2}\right] \mathrm{d}S = \int_{\partial B_{1}} 1 \mathrm{d}S.
> \end{align}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a few words, the thing to remember is that the ball is not changed when you interchange any two of the variables, and, similarly, that it is not changed when you send replace any variable with its negative. (Remember things you learned about integrating odd and even functions over $[-a,a]$ in one-variable calculus.)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, split $\partial B_1$ into $\partial B_1^+:=\{x\in \partial B_1|x_j\ge0\}$ and $\partial B_1^-:=\{x\in \partial B_1|x_j\lt0\}$, and note that$$\int_{\partial B_1^\color{blue}{-}}x_j\mathrm{d}S=-\int_{\partial B_1^\color{blue}{+}}x_j\mathrm{d}S.$$When we seek to evaluate $\int_{\partial B_1}x_jx_k\mathrm{d}S$ for $j\ne k$, we must have $n\ge2$, so we can perform a similar argument from cancellation, this time splitting based on the sign of $x_j/x_k$. (We don't need to worry too much about the zero-measure locus $x_k=0$, as it doesn't contribute to the integral). The final calculation uses the fact that $\int_{\partial B_1}x_j^2dS$ is $j$-independent, because $\partial B_1$ is invariant under permuting the Cartesian coordinates, so e.g. $\int_{\partial B_1}\left(x_j^2-x_\ell^2\right)dS=0$.